# haskell scanl tuple

Tags: haskell, tuples, fold

I have a list of tuples:

```
myList = [(1,1000), (2,2000), (3,3000),(4,4000]
```

And I would like to process this list so that the first element of each tuple remains the same and the second element is a cumulative. So for myList above, it would look like this:

```
[(1,1000),(2,3000),(3,6000),(4,10000)]
```

I've tried writing a function that uses `scanl1` but it wont compile:

```
myFunction myList = scanl1 f l
           where f = (\acc (x,y) -> (x, acc + y))
```

Any help, much appreciated

Comment: With questions like this, *always* post any compiler errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, the question has a typo: it should be `myList` rather than `l` in `myFunction myList = scanl1 f l`.

---

The main problem is the first argument to `scanl1` should have type `a -> a -> a`, but your scanning function `f` has type `Num c => c -> (b, c) -> (b,c)`, and there is no way to unify the types when one has both `a = c` and `a = (b,c)` (i.e. `c = (b,c)`, a "cannot construct infinite type" error).

The way to resolve this is to remember that `scanl1 f` applies `f` to the previous result and the next item in the list, in this case, both of the form `(x,y)`. This gives:

```
myFunction myList = scanl1 f myList
       where f (_,acc) (x,y) = (x, acc + y)
```

(NB. The underscore indicates an unused parameter.)

Comment: howdy - compiler narrative below:     

Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a0 = (a0, t0)
    Expected type: a0 -> a0 -> a0
      Actual type: a0 -> (a0, t0) -> (a0, t0)
    In the first argument of `scanl1', namely `f'
    In the expression: scanl1 f l

Comment: @AnthonyW, please edit information like that into the question, since it is much harder to read with the formatting removed! :) (Also, it's no longer necessary, your problem should be fixed.)

Comment: If this solves your problem, you should click the checkmark to indicate the answer as accepted. ([More info here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) :) )